# customize facebook share without using open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

I am trying to customize the Facebook share buttons being used on each of our landing pages we have built for each dealer.  The way the site was originally built in WP doesn't allow me to add the Open Graph meta to the  and get dealer specific info.  So, I'm trying to find a workaround but am not having any luck.  I'd like to specify the image to use when sharing, if possible, without using Open Graph.  Thank you in advanced for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the feed dialog to set custom tags in the sharing process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/

Check out the parameters: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5#params

Edit: Since v2.9 of the Graph API, you cannot set custom tags anymore, you have to use Open Graph tags in the source of the shared URL.